# watch is bad so how to change this

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using watch in angular and supposedly watch should not be used. I am using the following code

```
  $scope.$watch('mysevice.function()', function(tilda) {
      $scope.valueToShow = tilda ? true : false ;
    });
```

what do I need to do to refactor that?

**EDITED**
sorry edited question
function(tilda)......

Also

My code is working fine. What I was interested in is how to watch without using $watch

Comment: What is `tilda`? First step of refactoring is remove `? true : false`

Comment: `$scope.isTilda = function() { return tilda; }`? valueToShow depends exclusively on the value of tilda, so what's the point in watching 'mysevice.function()'?

Comment: the point is that I want to automatically push that on the site.

Comment: I will be showing a div based on true or false...and I dont want them to refresh the page....isTilda could change anytime in the background

Answer (score 0):

First be careful with the variable tilda in your function that appear as not declared.

Maybe you affect a $scope.tilda somewhere or do a global variable but it's the first issue in your code.

Then when you do `$scope.valueToShow = tilda` it's an affectation it's alwas true and the variable $scope.valueToShow become equal to tilda.

```
 $scope.$watch('mysevice.function()', function(online) {
      $scope.valueToShow == tilda ? true : false ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch a variable you need to use a function as first argument and return that variable.

```
  var tilda;// be sure to declare variable
  $scope.$watch(function() {
     return tilda;
  }, function(){
       $scope.valueToShow = tilda ? true : false ;
  });
```

Perhaps a better way is to use a function to change `tilda` and in that function also set `$scope.valueToShow`

```
function setTilda(value){
    tilda = value;
    $scope.valueToShow = tilda;
}
```

Comment: My code is working fine. What I was interested in is how to watch without using $watch

Comment: See `setTilda()` concept. Really not enough known about what your app is doing

Comment: sorry? I am very new to angular...can you explain?